# Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$. Show that the conjugacy class of $g$ is contained in $gG'$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question: Let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$.   Show that the conjugacy class of $g$ is contained in $gG'$, where $G'$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$.

I know the class equation, $|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_{i=1}^nC_G(g_i)$, so I was going to try and use this, but I can't seem to figure out a way to.  Or should I just take a random conjugate element and play with it from there?  Any help is always appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: What is $G’?{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Commutator subgroup of $G$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $xgx^{-1}g^{-1}\in G'$, and so $xgx^{-1}\in gG'$ for all $x\in G$. You really don't need anything else.

Comment: WOW, this was overthought WAY too much.

Comment: This makes it easy to show $xgx^{-1}\in G'g.$  Since $G'$ is normal, $G'g=gG'.$ But there is a more direct proof: use $g^{-1}xgx^{-1}\in G'.$